# Find everything but version number

Tags: regex

i have this text

```
Microsoft (R) Windows Script Host Version 5.8
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

58.0.3029 Copyright 2011 Google Inc.
```

I want is to find everything but

```
58.0.3029
```

I use this to find the pattern

```
\d+(\.\d+\.\d+)
```

So I have to find all but, the closest I could make was this

```
[\D+]+([\.\D+][\.\D+])
```

but it excludes other numbers 5.8 and 2011 too which I don't want to happen

Can you help me to find the right regex for that?

I use http://www.regexpal.com/ to test

I'm using a tool that's been developed with C#

Comment: yeah that finds it but my goal to find everything but these numbers (pattern)

Comment: What regex flavor/language?

Comment: @bobblebubble I using it with -math powershell but C# also will be okay

Comment: To select the stuff around, try with lookahead: [`^[\s\S]*\s(?=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)|\s[\s\S]*`](https://regex101.com/r/YJvGcD/2) (not sure if this works with your tool).

Comment: See http://www.regexpal.com/?fam=97578

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew this is the first one that actually did it but what language uses this? C# throws an exception becaue of the *SKIP *F

Comment: Ah, I only saw regexpal.com :) Surely it won't work in PowerShell. Use Jan's solution. Just match these numbers and remove from the string.

Comment: Just FYI: Only PCRE regex can skip matches. In .NET, to avoid getting some text, you match the text you do not need and match *and capture* the rest. See [this demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5cd%2b%5c.%5cd%2b%5c.%5cd%2b%7c%28%28%3f%3a%28%3f!%5cd%2b%5c.%5cd%2b%5c.%5cd%2b%29.%29%2b%29&i=Microsoft+%28R%29+Windows+Script+Host+Version+5.8%0d%0aCopyright+%28C%29+Microsoft+Corporation.+All+rights+reserved.%0d%0a%0d%0a58.0.3029+Copyright+2011+Google+Inc.), your matches are in Group 1.

Answer (score 1):

Use anchors (in multiline mode):

```
^\d[\d.]+
# match the start of the line
# require one digit
# followed by digit(s) and dot(s)
```

And replace the found match with `''`. See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/Nv414t/2).

Comment: this find those numbers, my goal is to find everything but those numbers. Pattern to be specific. I need it to find everything other than this pattern *.*.*

Comment: @YA: Just find the numbers and replace them with `''`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to capture everything but the version number, you can use the following:

```
([\s\S]*)\b\d+(?:\.\d+){2,}\s*([\s\S]*)
```

[Regex101 Example](https://regex101.com/r/T1lIUz/4)

Answer (score 0):

To get everything but the version number:

```
([\s\S]*)\b(\d+\.\d+\.\d+)\b([\s\S]*)
```

Replace with: `$1$3`

[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/O9jrlc/3)

Output:

```
Microsoft (R) Windows Script Host Version 5.8
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

 Copyright 2011 Google Inc.
```